# Include multiple custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, include

Hi i want to include 2 different custom post types in  my functions files:

```
include("portfolio/portfolio-post-type.php"); 
include("gallery/gallery-post-type.php");
```

But they seem to break WordPress, it only works if I include only one at a time, do I  need to wrap this within a function?

Comment: what do those files contain?

Comment: this is what os included on each file(with different names for the post type):http://cl.ly/393s2U1N2z0b

Comment: can you post each file (separately) exactly as is on pastebin.com ? Alos tell us exactly what the error message is. If you have non, use WP_DEBUG to discover it

Comment: ok here re the two:http://pastebin.com/q0x9Mp7E http://pastebin.com/3tiW2RN1

Answer (score 2):

The reason you can't include both files is that you've named all the functions the same. You can't have two functions named post_type or portfolio_messages etc.

Also I see a few other things wrong with your code.

- The function names should be unique to your plugin/theme. So prepend the names with your theme/plugin name. So try mytheme_gallery_post_type and mytheme_portfolio_post_type etc.
- The rewrite array should not be a part of $labels. Make it a part of $args instead.
- Don't run the taxonomy and custom post type names through the internationalization function. That is the first arg to register_post_type and register_taxonomy should not be run through __().

Comment: Thank you so much, changing the function names solve my problem.